# Lots of views in one day

Tags: discussion

I noticed that this question ([Burning Arduinos one after another](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/43188/13425)) got almost 4K views in one day. That seems odd since the average on arduino.se seems to be about 25 (guestimate). Is this view count correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was probably a HNQ (Hot Network Question) - see the side bar that appears on everyone's page. If the question looks interesting it will draw in a lot of views. I can even imagine that the title "Burning Arduinos one after another" might have got people interested.

Comment: I didn't think of that. That makes sense.